# SQLite for read-only applications?

Tags: windows, sqlite

Will SQLite work OK for a multi-user read-only application where the database resides on a Windows network drive?

Answer (score 1):

I think that, if you are only reading, then yes. According to [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) writing might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the SQLite work is done in memory.  If you have enough memory available SQLite won't do much I/O other than read the database once.

Comment: That's per-process/connection though.  If you're opening the application a lot or recycling new connections frequently that could cause issues with network transfer.

Comment: Doubt that the SQLite transfers would compare with SQL/Server or Oracle connections.